# How to find out which ecosystem.json file is used to start a process in pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

I have a bunch of processes started by PM2 on a server. `pm2 list` shows this:

[image]

I'm sure that each of them is started with an ecosystem config file. What I want to know is that what pm2 ecosystem config file is used to start for example process with the id 62 and the ecosystem config file path.

So is there any pm2 command for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can differ processes by app name (so you should set unique name in each ecosystem config file) or you can use a [NODE_APP_INSTANCE](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/#specific-environment-variables) variable to differ processes in cluster.

[EDIT]

There is no way how to find specific ecosystem file but you can use `pm2 describe [processID/name]` to find directory where was `pm2 start` executed (`exec cwd` parameter). If there is more ecosystem files than 1 you can differ processes only by name.

Comment: Thanks, But someone else starts those processes and I want to find the ecosystem config file paths.

Comment: I editted answer, you cant find specific ecosystem file, but zou can find a directory of execution, i might help if you have only 1 ecosystem file per project